# C# JSON toObject switches day and month around

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

I get a formatted string from the backend which looks like this:
2019-03-06T18:06:00

I can confirm this in debug in the first line of my included code.

When the second line is executed, the result is:
03/06/2019 18:06:00

Problem is that the day and month are switched around.

Here are my code:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jsonCars = assignmentsResult.cars;
List<CarsViewModel> assignments = jsonCars.ToObject<List<CarViewModel>>();
```

The property in the `CarViewModel` are of type `string`. I tried `DateTime`, but that resolved in:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime'. Path 'cars[0].created'.

What could I do differently?

Comment: Are you sure that's just not a printing issue? US date format is mm/dd/yyyy. So it might be parsing the date correctly and just showing it in a format you are unfamiliar with?

Comment: "I don't like that date time uses my local format to show the value" is common (and I personally think completely misguided) complain. Please make sure to post real [MCVE] along with exact values you see as result (preferably using `ToString("o")` for all DateTime fields so we don't need to guess you timezone and CultureInfo.

Comment: Have you tried setting serialization settings like :`var jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "dd-MM-yyyyThh:mm:ss" };` and then use that as an argument to deserialize function?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using the DateTime types for date values. I guess the issue with serialization may be because for some of the array objects the value forcreated can be null.You can try using a nullable Datetime(DateTime ?) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert `2019-03-06T18:06:00` to `DateTime` you can then convert it to string in any format you want. Example:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-03-06T18:06:00");
string correctFormat = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
Console.WriteLine(correctFormat);
```

Will output:

```
03/06/2019 18:06
```

So it would be better to use `DateTime` to store your values, you can then manipulate them to print out what you like.

Comment: I'm not in charge of parsing the json to object. I wanted it to be a one-liner. But the toObject() is not doing a good job with DateTime objects, so I have no other choice than to do it myself then like you suggest.